# $8$ teachers divided among $4$ schools. How many divisions are possible?

Tags: combinatorics

This is related to [How many ways can 10 teachers be divided among 5 schools?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60096/how-many-ways-can-10-teachers-be-divided-among-5-schools/60226#60226), but my question doesn't appear to have a direct answer there.

> If 8 new teachers are to be divided among 4 schools, how many
>   divisions are possible?

The answer is $4^8$ because the teachers are **distinguishable**.  But another way to reach this solution starts with
$$\sum_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4=8}\binom{8}{n_1\ n_2\ n_3\ n_4}$$

We are dividing distinguishable things (teachers). How do we compute this summation? How do we count all the vectors $(n_1,n_2, n_3, n_4)$ such that $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 = 8$?

Comment: Counting the number of non-negative solutions of $n_1+\cdots+n_4=8$ is not hard. It is a quite indirect way of finding the answer to the question.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I am familiar with finding the number of integer-valued vectors as discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504187/combinatorics-problem-on-20-people-12-months-and-distinguishable-groups) if that's what you mean. My question is how to count the possible vectors when we have **distinguishable** objects.

Comment: You gave the answer $4^8$ already. We can use the Multinomial Theorem (putting all $x_i=1$) to get this, but it is much easier to count the functions directly.

Comment: If we didn't know the answer was $4^8$ already, what is our reasoning to put all $x_i = 1$?

Comment: Same reason as putting $x=1$ in the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$ to get the sum of the binomial coefficients. The Multinomial Theorem gives $(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)^8$ as a sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to count all possible ways to partition $8$ distinguishable teachers into $4$ groups. Use the Multinomial Theorem, and set $x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot  x_3 \cdot  x_4 = 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = \large\mathbf{1}$ since only makes sense to count each possibility once.

$$\sum_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4=8}\binom{8}{n_1\ n_2\ n_3\ n_4} x_1^{n_1}x_2^{n_2}x_3^{n_3}x_4^{n_4} =\sum_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4=8}\binom{8}{n_1\ n_2\ n_3\ n_4}  1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = (1 + 1 + 1 + 1)^8 = 4^8 $$

Answer (score 2):

This is just classic stars and bars problem. The solution is:

$$\binom{n+m-1}{n} = \binom{8+4-1}{8}$$

if it's allowed a a school to have no teacher. While if a school must have at least one teacher the solution is:

$$\binom{k-1}{n-1} = \binom{7}{3}$$

For better explantion on this method you can read about it one the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29). It has a really nice explanation.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and +1.